# How to use logic with flutter/dart constants

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the color of a text widget based on a condition. If the variable `isDark` is true, change color to black, else change color to white.

Using the code:

```
    ListWidget(BuildContext context) => listItems
        .map(
          (e) => Center(
            child: Text(
              e,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  // The statement below highlights an "invalid constant" error on isDark
                  color: isDark ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
```

How can I work around it or is there a better approach to doing it?

I also tried creating a `const` variable like so:

```
     if (!theme.darkMode)
       const color = Colors.white;
     else
       const color = Colors.black;
```

but color still returns as an invalid constant.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio to edit your Flutter project, the suggested fix, removing the `const` keyword, will appear and you probably won't ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is okay. Just remove the `const` keyword from `TextStyle`.